# Implementing a scheduling algorithm (assignment)

Tags: c++, algorithm, queue

So I am on my 2nd year of computer science and I am struggling with a part of one of my assignments.

Basically, we had to make a stack, a queue and a scheduling algorithm.

I've made the stack and queue part which will technically give me a pass, but I would like to do the remaining part as well just to be sure.

We're allowed to use ONLY iostream library, nothing else.

These are the .h files provided by our teacher:
http://pastebin.com/TcBzULZj

We HAVE to use these.
I am struggling with the algorithm as it is supposed to be a subclass of queue, using an integer for priority and storing integer values to represent process IDs.

How should I approach that?

I am not asking you to do my homework for me or anything like that, I just want to tips and a little push in the right direction :)

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
EDIT

I tried to do it this way:

http://pastebin.com/mFchEc6T

It does compile and start, but as soon as I try to do anything in the program it gives some memory error and turns off my program.

I guess there's something wrong with the pointers but I dont know what.

[image]

Basically the idea behind that function was to go through all the nodes from the top of the queue and compare their priority to the priority of "temp" node.

It would swap places with nodes as long as "temp" had higher priority than them (green on picture) and as soon as it hit a node with the same priority (blue) it would stop there and wait for its turn, before nodes with higher priority (red) are done.

I bet these pointers are messed up but I just can't get my head around it for life, even though I struggled with this for like 2 days already.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I don't really know how to approach this and add that functionality to my existing code.

Comment: Please add the code you're having problems with to your question, and clarify to address specifically the problems you're having with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adding a new value with priority P after all values with priorities higher than P.

Pop values from the beginning of the list.

For example:

If you have values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 with priorities 99, 54, 111, 27, 978

In list you have: 5(978), 3(111), 1(99), 2(54), 4(27).

If you need add value 6 with priority 105, you add it after value 3 with priority 111.

Comment: I have that already implemented in my code. Each node can (but doesn't have to) have a a priority value. I just cant figure out how to sort them and then Pop values in priority order.

Comment: You could find right position in list when you adding new node.

Comment: You should add new node before first node with smaller priority.

Comment: Ah I understand. Thank you for your help. 
But the thing is, I need to have a "normal queue", as well as a priority queue. 
I already have a normal queue up and working, but now I need to add the priority queue functionality. Right now the default priority = 0 so the queue operates FCFS. But you can change the priority when you initialize it (q.Enqueue(i); in this case the priority is 0; Enqueue(i, j); in this the priority is j). I'd like to make it so it works as FCFS as long as all the nodes have the same priority, but when there's a node with higher priority it should serve it first.

Comment: Sorry it is so unclear but I really struggle to wrap my mind around it myself.

Comment: So, maybe I don't understand you, sorry. For example you have three elements in queue (priorities in parentheses): 3(100), 2(200), 1(500).
You should place it in list such way: 1(500), 2(200), 3(100).
When you need to serve element you should take it from the beginning of list.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the simple example of queue with priorities.

```
#include <iostream>

class Queue {
public:
    Queue() :
        queue( 0 )
    {
    }

    void Push( int value, int priority = 0 );
    bool Pop( int& value );

private:
    struct Node {
        Node* Next;
        int Value;
        int Priority;       

        Node( int value, int priority ) :
            Next( 0 ),
            Value( value ),
            Priority( priority )
        {
        }
    };
    Node* queue;

    Queue( const Queue& );
    Queue& operator=( const Queue& );
};


void Queue::Push( int value, int priority)
{
    Node* node = new Node( value, priority );
    if( queue == 0 || queue->Priority < node->Priority ) {
        node->Next = queue;
        queue = node;
    } else {
        Node* i = queue;
        while( i->Next != 0 && node->Priority <= i->Next->Priority ) {
            i = i->Next;
        }
        node->Next = i->Next;
        i->Next = node;
    }
}

bool Queue::Pop( int& value )
{
    if( queue == 0 ) {
        return false;
    }
    value = queue->Value;
    Node* tmp = queue;
    queue = queue->Next;
    delete tmp;
    return true;
}


int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    Queue queue;

    queue.Push( 3, 100 );
    queue.Push( 2, 200 );
    queue.Push( 1, 500 );

    int x;
    while( queue.Pop( x ) ) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```